# How can I free space in main from dynamically allocated array , that has been created in a pointer function

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Ok so lets say I have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool *returnPtr(int size){
    bool *arr = new bool[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){ //randomly filling array to provide example
        arr[i] = rand()%2;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    bool *ptr = returnPtr(6);

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        cout<<ptr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
}
```

Can I free space by writing this at the end in main:

```
 delete[]ptr;
```

Comment: Yes, you've to free the memory using `delete []ptr;` at the end of main.

Comment: Please be aware that manually allocating memory like this should always be avoided as much as possible. For your use case `std::vector` is suitable, except that `std::vector<bool>` specifically is a bit of a weird exception, but `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<char>` works fine for `false`/`true` as well.

Comment: You **Can** free the memory at the end-of-`main()`, but there is no need. The memory will be freed on program exit as well. If you are using `valgrind` or another memory use/error check, then yes, free the memory in `main()` otherwise, that memory will still be shown as allocated on program exit by the memory check.